# how to strip out the http"// in php?

Tags: php

supposed a variable named $url,whcih value maybe `$url=http://www.example.com` or `$url=http://example.com` or `$url=www.example.com`

now, i want to echo the $url in `www.example.com` style, how to does this? thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$url="http://www.example.com";
$data = parse_url($url);
echo $data["host"];
```

PHP parse_url: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: compliment it with this if (substr($data["host"],0,3) != 'www') {
  echo "<br />www.".$data["host"];
 }

Answer (score 3):

use `str_replace` function

```
echo str_replace('http://', '' , 'http://www.example.com');
$url =  str_replace('http://', '' , 'http://www.example.com');
```

Comment: can use str_ireplace just in case

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to do the job. Search the http in the url through strpos if found replace with blank.

```
if (strpos($url,'http://') !== false)
{
   $url=str_replace('http://','',$url);
}
```